# How to implement projective geometry in MMA?

Tags: geometry, logic

I'd like to implement 2D projective geometry in Mathematica, making use of the `FindEquationalProof` 
command. Up to [Wiki ru.wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)
(This topic is better written in Russian edition than in English one.), the classical projective plane P
 is defined by the following axioms. 
The first four of these are required.

P1. Through two different points P and Q of the plane P passes a straight line, and only one.

P2. Any two lines have a common point.

P3. There are three points not lying on one straight line.

P4. Each line contains at least three points.

Additional axioms are the following:

P5. Axiom of Desargues. If triangles ABC and A'B'C 'are such that straight lines AA',
 BB 'and CC' intersect at point O, then the intersection points of the pairs of 
 corresponding sides AB and A'B '(P), BC and B'C' ( R), AC and A'C '(Q) lie on one straight line.

P6. Pappus Axiom. If l and l 'are two different lines, A, B, C are three different points on
   the line l, and A', B ', C' are three different points l ', and all these points are different
   from O - the points of intersection of lines l and l ', then the intersection points of
   the pairs of corresponding sides AB' and A'B (P), BC 'and B'C (R), AC' and A'C (Q) lie on
   the same line.

P7. Fano's axiom. Let A, B, C, D be points, no three of which lie on the same line. 
   Let's draw all six straight lines connecting these points (AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD). 
   Denote the intersection point of AB and CD by P, AC and BD by Q and AD and BC by R 
   (diagonal points). These diagonal points do not lie on one straight line.

It is not so simple to formulate the above axioms in Wolfram language. There are two types
 of objects of projective plane: points and lines. There is a relation: a point belongs to a line.
Here is my attempt.

```
axioms={ForAll[{p,q} ∈ points,p!= q,Exists[m ∈ lines, el[p,m]&&el[q,m]]],
ForAll[{m,k} ∈ lines,Exists[ p ∈ points,el[p,m]&&el[p,k]]],
Exists[{p,q,r} ∈ points, ForAll[k ∈ lines, 
Not[el[p,k]]||Not[el[q,k]]||Not[el[r,k]]]],...}
```

I stop at  axiom P3 because of

```
Exists[{p, q, r} ∈ points,ForAll[k ∈ lines, 
 Not[el[p, k]] || Not[el[q, k]] || Not[el[r, k]]]]
```

> Exists::ivar: {p,q,r}∈points is not a valid variable.

Constructive criticism is welcome.

Comment: Look at the documentation of `Exists` and `Element`: The proper syntax is `Exists[{p, q, r}, (p|q|r) ∈ points, ...]`

Comment: @Lucas Lang: Thank you. Unfortunately, the changed code produces another errorExists::msgs: Evaluation of {(p|q|r)\[Element]points,\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ForAll]\), \(k \[Element] lines\)]\((\(! el[p, k]\) || \(! el[q, k]\) || \(! el[r, k]\))\)\)} generated message(s) {ForAll::ivar}.

Comment: Look at the documentation of `ForAll`: your syntax wrong here as well

Comment: @Lucas Lang: Are you serious? I am waititing fog for a serious constructive answer.

Comment: Sorry if I came across too harsh - the comment was intended to be constructive. Your syntax error is exactly the same for `ForAll` as it was for `Exists`. If you look at the documentation, you'll see that the syntax for both is `ForAll[vars,conds,expr]`.

Comment: @Lucas Lang: Thank you. Exists[{p, q, r}, (p | q | r) \[Element] points, 
 ForAll[k, k \[Element] lines, 
  Not[el[p, k]] || Not[el[q, k]] || Not[el[r, k]]]] works well. How about the axioms P4-P7?